# Shell script syntax highlighting library

Tags: objective-c, c, shell, syntax-highlighting

Is there any (open source) shell script syntax highlighting library available in C/C++ or Objective-C?

I've searched google and SO, but all of the hits reference some specific application's syntax highlighting support, instead of a general library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is. [RegexHighlightView](https://github.com/KayK/RegexHighlightView) is a quite good library. It supports both Windows shell-style and Unix SH-style source code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Shouldn't be too difficult to fork and port to OS X.

Answer (score 1):

How about [source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight.html)? It is a library and command line utility under the GNU project.

It has much more languages than shell scripts, but the more the better...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found one for OS X too. Looks great: [Fragaria](https://github.com/mugginsoft/Fragaria).